# Is there a way to turn this summation into a matrix multiplication?

Tags: matrices, summation

I have two vectors $\mathbf{s}, \mathbf{p}$ of length $n$, and I need to compute a vector $\mathbf{\pi}$ defined by

$$\pi_i=\sum_{j=1}^is_j(p_j-p_i)$$

for $i$ from $1$ to $n$.

I suspect this computation could be sped up considerably if it was vectorized, and it seems like I should be able to find $\pi$ by a matrix multiplication, but I can't quite figure out how.

Answer (score 1):

we have:
$$
\pi_i=\sum_{j=1}^is_j(p_j-p_i) = \sum_{j=1}^is_j p_j-\left(\sum_{j=1}^is_j\right) p_i= 
$$
$$=
\left(\sum_{j=1}^{i-1}s_jp_j\right)-\left(\sum_{j=1}^{i-1}s_j\right) p_i
$$
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
\pi_1\\\pi_2\\\pi_3\\\cdot\\\cdot\\\pi_n
\end{bmatrix}=
\begin{bmatrix}
0&0&0&0&\cdots &0\\
s_1&-s_1&0 &0&\cdots&0\\
s_1&s_2&-(s_1+s_2)&0&\cdots&0\\
s_1&s_2&s_3&-(s_1+s_2+s_3)& \cdots&0\\
\cdots\\
s_1&s_2& \cdots&\cdots&s_{n-1}&-\sum_{j=1}^{i-1}s_j
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
p_1\\p_2\\p_3\\\cdot\\\cdot\\p_n
\end{bmatrix}
$$

Answer (score 0):

It depends if the cumulative sum of a vector is a vector command.
Let 
$$A_i=\sum_{j=1}^is_jp_j\\
B_i=\sum_{j=1}^is_j\\
X_i=A_i-p_iB_i$$
In Matlab, it would be:
A=cumsum(s.*p);
B=cumsum(p);
X=A-p.*B;